# React Native reanimated animation not working as intended

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native reanimated 2 to animate some action buttons from my tinder-like test app, it goes like this, each time user profile screen is focused I do a fetch with axios and depending on the data I get from my backend I want to show or hide (with a cool slide up or down animation) the action buttons.

Currently I see no animation at all, I tried console logging everything and useEffect seems to be firing many times, complete console log looks like this:

```
Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -100
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionGoToChat to: -100
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionCreateChat to: -100
 LOG  detail user id:  19
 LOG  userHasChatWithMe null
 LOG  userHasMatchWithMe null
 LOG  userHasChatWithMe null
 LOG  userHasMatchWithMe null
 LOG  sentLikeAction 0
 LOG  detail user id:  19
 ERROR  Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in observerComponent (at UserProfileCard.js:589)
 LOG  showLikeActions true
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -100
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -99.64524765795433
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -96.18183676259504
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -89.83092353468986
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -81.48457402835008
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -72.4952608807508
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -62.3531741654983
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -52.116607099460104
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -42.76587085277234
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -33.42679658650352
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -24.915353292676944
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -17.78534118920777
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -11.214048923475948
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -5.99017112282276
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -1.4367781923471195
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 2.146500168828348
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 4.7057823302509085
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 6.653191796151024
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 7.908609834757876
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 8.579927836569588
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 8.773022201945137
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 8.60781283670089
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 8.151567388573786
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 7.487226039379407
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 6.736647087760782
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 5.864463032704875
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 5.017895809302941
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 4.129875259020465
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 3.284276559892847
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 2.5475959806455877
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 1.84230892923561
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 1.2255299071159116
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 0.7008527282509268
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 0.29056908556263666
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.06038210244415409
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.3162884201922212
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.5167338820701801
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.6523612187683206
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.7325889503640921
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.7668278262354822
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.7651511437560337
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.7353812089993071
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.6877460846409345
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.6227421287808769
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.5486266285148166
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.47027619306089624
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.3962067382580416
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.3200988957104902
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.24891748163310745
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.1878692280469319
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.13028483028403468
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.08338687685335412
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.041410051063927145
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: -0.009098641973069584
 LOG  Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to: 0
```

My component logic:

```
import { useSharedValue, useAnimatedStyle, withTiming, withSpring } from 'react-native-reanimated';

const isFocused = useIsFocused();

    const bottomPositionCreateChat = useSharedValue(-100); // initial hidden state
    const bottomPositionGoToChat = useSharedValue(-100);
    const bottomPositionLikeActions = useSharedValue(-100);

    const createChatStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        console.log("Animating bottomPositionCreateChat to:", bottomPositionCreateChat.value);
        return {
          bottom: bottomPositionCreateChat.value,
        };
      });

    const createGoToChatStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        console.log("Animating bottomPositionGoToChat to:", bottomPositionGoToChat.value);
        return {
          bottom: bottomPositionGoToChat.value,
        };
    });

    const createLikeActionsStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        console.log("Animating bottomPositionLikeActions to:", bottomPositionLikeActions.value);
        return {
          bottom: bottomPositionLikeActions.value,
        };
    });


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('showCreateChat',showCreateChat);
        bottomPositionCreateChat.value = withSpring(showCreateChat ? 0 : -100, {
          damping: 15, // Lower values make the spring bouncier
          stiffness: 150, // How stiff the spring is. Lower values may lead to bouncier animations
          mass: 1, // Mass of the object being animated
        });
      }, [showCreateChat]);
      
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log('showGoToChat',showGoToChat);
        bottomPositionGoToChat.value = withSpring(showGoToChat ? 0 : -100, {
          damping: 15,
          stiffness: 150,
          mass: 1,
        });
      }, [showGoToChat]);
      
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log('showLikeActions',showLikeActions);
        bottomPositionLikeActions.value = withSpring(showLikeActions ? 0 : -100, {
          damping: 15,
          stiffness: 150,
          mass: 1,
        });
      }, [showLikeActions]);

   


    
   

    useEffect(() => {
        if(isFocused)
        {
            root.userStore.setMatchModalVisible(false);
            getHasMatchOrChat(root.userStore.detailUser.id);
        }
    }, [isFocused]);


    const getHasMatchOrChat = async (id) => 
    {
        
        setLoadedChats(false);
        try 
        {
            console.log('looking for matches or chats');
            /*
            setShowCreateChat(false);
            setShowGoToChat(false);
            setShowLikeActions(false);
            */  
        let payload =  {user_id:id, auth_user_id:root.userStore.user.id};
        console.log('payload',payload);
        let response = await http.get(env.BASE_URL+'/api/matches/get-has-match-or-chat-by-id', {params:payload});

        console.log('userHasChatWithMe',response.data.userHasChatWithMe);
        console.log('userHasMatchWithMe',response.data.userHasMatchWithMe);
        console.log('sentLikeAction',response.data.sentLikeAction);

        let userHasMatchWithMe = response.data.userHasMatchWithMe;
        let userHasChatWithMe = response.data.userHasChatWithMe;
        let sentLikeAction = response.data.sentLikeAction;


        if( (matchedNow || userHasMatchWithMe ) && !previousWasChat )
        {
            setShowCreateChat(true);
        }
        else if(userHasChatWithMe && !previousWasChat && loadedChats )
        {
            setShowGoToChat(true);
        }
        else if(!userHasMatchWithMe && !userHasChatWithMe && sentLikeAction == 0)
        {
            setShowLikeActions(true);
        }
            


        //setLoadedChats(true);
        //root.mapStore.setShowChatIcon(true);
        
            }
            catch (error)
            {
                console.log(error);
                //setLoadedChats(false);
                throw error;
            }

    };
```

My action buttons:

```
<View style={{ flex:1,position:'relative',padding:0,overflow:'hidden' }}>
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={ ()=>{ createChat() } } style={[{ position:'absolute',left:(Dimensions.get('window').width / 2) - 50,alignSelf:'center',width:90,height:90,borderRadius:90/2,backgroundColor:'#662C91',borderWidth:0,borderColor:'#662C91',elevation:10 ,alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', bottom:100 }, createChatStyle]}>
                  <IonIcon name='chatbubble' style={{ fontSize:50, color:'white' }}/>
 </TouchableOpacity>
      
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={ ()=>{ goToChat() } } style={[{ position:'absolute',left:(Dimensions.get('window').width / 2) - 50,alignSelf:'center',width:90,height:90,borderRadius:90/2,backgroundColor:'#FF7B9C',backgroundColor:'#662C91',borderWidth:0,borderColor:root.uiStore.primaryColor,elevation:10 ,alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', bottom:100}, createGoToChatStyle]}>    
        <IonIcon name='chatbubble-ellipses' style={{ fontSize:50, color:'white' }}/>
 </TouchableOpacity>
      
           
<TouchableOpacity  activeOpacity={1} onPress={ ()=>{ onDisliked();  } } style={[{   width:90,height:90,left:15, borderRadius:90/2,overflow:'hidden',backgroundColor:'rgb(255, 167, 46)',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',elevation:10, position:'absolute', bottom:100 }, createLikeActionsStyle]}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon name="close" style={{ color:'white', fontSize:60 }}/>  
                </TouchableOpacity>  
             </View>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue just that your container for these animating views needs to be `<Animated.View>`, rather than just `<View>`?

Comment: that's what I thought but added the Animated.View and I'm still getting same results.

Comment: @gabogabans - try wrapping each of the views you are intending to animate with an <Animated.View>, and applying your animated style to that wrapping Animated View. You essentially have 3 different animations you are trying to do, and 3 different animated styles. So wrap each of your TouchableOpacity with their own Animated.View, and apply the animated style there instead.